# May the LORD reward you for your kindness

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras

I want to translate [this sentence](http://www.allaboutgod.com/truth-topics/kindness.htm) into Spanish:

> May the LORD reward you for your kindness

My attempt:

> Que Dios te recompense por tu amabilidad .

Is my translation correct?

Thank you.

Comment: I would prefer "Que el señor te recompense por tu amabilidad". Hispanic people also refer to God as "el señor" (the lord). However the translation is correct.

Comment: In Mexico we would use: "Que Dios te lo pague", which is a common response to acts of kindness. I believe this is what you are looking for...if you needed Mexican-Spanish.

Comment: @luisluix In Spain too, we use to use this sentence ("Que Dios te lo pague"). However, in the context the OP has to translate it, this usual translation may not apply, and he better translates as the approved answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your translation is correct, however

> Dios = God
>
> The Lord = El Señor

So a more exact translation would be

```
Que El Señor recompense tu amabilidad.
```

or a a longer version

```
Que El Señor te recompense por tu amabilidad
```