# Correct way to say United states of America in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, gramática

After googling for half an hour, finally I found the meaning of **`Estados Unidos`**. It means **United States**.

Then, I added the preposition **de** to make it:

> **`United States of America`** -> **`Estados Unidos de America`**.

Does it make sense in Spanish?

Please help correct my sentence!

Comment: It is correct !! you are just missing an accent in América. Next time just type "united states of america in spanish" in google and you won't spend that much time getting to the translation.

Comment: BTW. For sure soon someone will mark this question as off-topic since this stack does not accept requests for translations, but I don't mind :-)

Comment: @DGaleano We don't accept requests for bulk translations with no show of a previous effort by the asker; but this is not the case, in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Gorpik. As far as I've seen, there is no consistency.  Sometimes these questions are flagged and sometimes they are not. I really don't mind helping people with translations, but the community is the ruler. In fact one of my most voted answers so far was asked in exactly the same way as this one (before your edit) and has been marked off-topic for this reason. If you care to check it out it is  here http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/15176/may-the-lord-reward-you-for-your-kindness

Comment: @DGaleano In my opinion, the other question should not have been closed. It is wrong to submit a text and ask for corrections; but it is OK to ask for a specific sentence or construction, as both these questions do. The reason is that these questions can be reused by another visitor who is looking for the same. But this could be a discussion for Meta, not for these comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We say both **Estados Unidos** and **Estados Unidos de América**.

- In normal conversations you may say *Estados Unidos*.
- However, the official name in Spanish is *Estados Unidos de América*.

If you ever have another question like this, you always have the trick of going to the Wikipedia article in English and then selecting the article in Spanish. In this case you would access https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estados_Unidos

Comment: Or just check a dictionary.

Comment: Even in formal context, you don't always use the full official name: I can't imagine a news article (unless very specific) about *Estado Plurinacional de Bolivia*, or an OEA convention where the attendants's sign reads *Estados Unidos Mexicanos*, just as much as I can't imagine either with *Estados Unidos de América*: they'll just go by *Estados Unidos*